# npm run serve does not work and throws strange error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, localhost

I'm trying to simulate my vue.js project in the given environment in vue-cli and sadly the command to start the server (as described in many videos) does not work.

I'm in the root directory of my project where I did "vue create project_name".
Then I switched to the currently created folder and did "npm run serve" and this error popped up (the * are just unnecessary path names, "another_test" is the root of my project):

`ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\*\*\*\learning-vue\#test_project_vue\another_test\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=localhost&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'C:\*\*\*\learning-vue\#test_project_vue\another_test'`

Sb has an idea? I almost tried EVERY forum post from like deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, then doing "npm cache clean --force" and then "npm install". I moved it away from desktop, etc...

I just want the localhost to work just like in literally ANY video I saw. But it never gets to the point where it works cause the above error occurs every time! ( ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error & then the message..)

(Maybe useful and I think the problem is there: I'm in a network of my university and when I did "npm run serve" the first time, the windows defender popped up with a firewall-warning and asked for admin rights (gave it username and password) and I had to tick something..)

btw: my package.json file looks/looked like this & then I replaced the "scripts" part as recommended from a course I do:
[package.json file in my projects root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wCwo.png)

-> first tried with that config and then replaced the "scripts" snippet with:

```js
"scripts": {  
  "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",  
  "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",  
  "lint": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

Appreciate any useful help!

Comment: $ npm run dev (maybe??)

Comment: "npm run dev" does not work, cause when I do "npm run" in my project root, just "serve, build, lint" are available scripts